# What are the Database replication methods used in your projects? If you are using CDC, how is it useful and what are the challenges?

Tags: database, database-replication, cdc

This is a question for most of the DBA's / Information experts at product level. I need the solution for as many different databases as possible. So please provide the details of the replication methods used. For e.g:

- Database: Oracle 11i
- Replication method: Oracle ODI-EE with GoldenGate
- Pros: Can be integrated with any databases, etc
- Cons: Cannot be integrated with so and so databases, some other generic problems

Some may have been using Trigger based or Custom PL-SQL based solutions. Please specify the problems you are facing in that scenario.

*I am not only looking for CDC solutions, so please don't restrict to any CDC based solutions.*

I tried searching for the solution and could not get any consolidated answer, so if this is an existing question, please share the link and feel free to close this.

Comment: `ODI-EE = Oracle Data Integrator Enterprise Edition`.
What is CDC?

Comment: CDC = Change Database Capture. It is a solution offered by different vendors for db replication. Some of the products like Infosphere CDC gives real time sychronization.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up in a trigger-based CDC solution, encapsulated in an own product MOVEX CDC.
https://gitlab.com/otto-group-solution-provider/movex-cdc

Why?
Especially to:

- avoid supplemental logging
- Zero dependency to DB operation
- Quick and easy installation at user level